# Solaris Flar image share across the network using NFS

Tags: networking, solaris, nfs

```
bash-3.2# exportfs -av
shareall -F nfs
share_nfs: /flar/sol10-flar.flar: Value too large for defined data type
```

I am trying to share the solaris10 flar image on to the other server using NFS. I am getting the above error message.

Answer (score 3):

You want to share the `/flar` directory, not the `sol10-flar.flar` file.  Once the directory is there, you'll be able to boot other hosts from it by calling the full path of the file, as the directory is shared via NFS.  You'll be prompted to enter the path to the archive, where you'll need to enter a path like `/net/NFS_SERVER_HOSTNAME/flar/sol10-flar.flar`.